# Переход от одной системы координат к другой Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Имеется 2 GameObject, которые друг с другом по факту не связаны. У объекта 1 есть дочерний GameObject, мне необходимо поместить дочерний объект в точку, которая была бы удалена от центра объекта 1  на расстояние равное красному отрезку.

Comment: А причем здесь тогда второй объект, если он никак с первым и дочерним не связан, а дело все вообще в отрезке?

Comment: Штука в том, что потом 2 объект будет перемещаться в эту самую дочернюю точку..и нужно чтобы расстояние от центра 1 объекта до центра второго было равно красному отрезку

Comment: И тем не менее, я не понимаю, что вы хотите. `Имеется 2 GameObject`, потом откуда-то появляется дочерний объект, в итоге всего этих объектов, включая дочерний, сколько?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ничего не считать можно сделать так:

1. Добавьте в чайлды первому гейм обджекту пустой гейм обджект, назовем его `place`.
2. Переместите его в точку, в которую необходимо перемещать Ваш второй гейм обджект.
3. Переместите ваш второй гейм обджект в точку, где находится объект place:

   ```
     transform.position = place.transform.position;
   ```

кажется все

Comment: в том и дело, что надо посчитать,  а не руками

Comment: @Fred зачем надо?

Comment: чтобы впоследствии на объект 1 вещать к примеру какой то объект на расстоянии равном красному отрезку

Comment: @Fred не понятно

Comment: @Fred то что я описал сделает ровно то, что описано в вопросе - поместит второй геймобджект в желаемую точку без фактической связи предок - потомок, если Вам надо иное, то вопрос задан не корректно

Comment: как найти эту точку куда переместить второй объект?

Comment: @Fred Вы визуально ее определили, поместите туда пустой обьект в редакторе

Comment: Вы не понимаете...мне необходимо к объекту 1 присоединить дочерний какой-то объект, пусть пустой, и поместить его от центра родителя в точку, расстояние от которой до центра объекта 1 будет равно расстоянию от пусть угла объекта 2 до центра объекта 2(красный отрезок)

Comment: @Fred что Вам мешает поставить туда объект руками в редакторе?

Comment: то что это не единичная операция

Comment: @Fred следовало бы это указать в вопросе

Comment: @Fred https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html